# Developing a flexible estimation strategy for longitudinal data with heavy clustering, covariates with missings and interval censoring

Tags: bootstrap, cox-model, multiple-imputation, interval-censoring, competing-risks

This is a general question for R users that are familar with interval censoring in survival analyses. I have clinical registry data at hand and aim to compare the one-year incidence for two groups (size about 1k each) for an outcome (amputation) with an incidence of about 10%.

**1st challenge: Interval censoring**

The outcome was assessed retrospectively up to three times during followup by calling the study participants. Thus, we just know that the event happened for instances anytime between baseline and 1st telephone interview (or 2nd and 3rd interview).

**2nd challenge: Heavy censoring and competing risks**

In the data a considerable amount of patients (about 30%) could not be contacted again and/or died during the first year after baseline. Thus, one needs to account for censoring and perhaps the competing risk "death".

**3rd challenge: Missings**

The about 20 covariates suitable to adjust for confounding contain a lot of missings (5%-95%).

**4th challenge: Clustering**

The data comes from about 25 medical centers, where some did treat a substantial proportion of patients and others only a tiny fraction.

**Solution:**

I have a complex bootstrap approach in mind for analyzing this dataset. I would like to apply block bootstrapping whereby whole centers were re-sampled with replacement (resampling the higher level) using the *boot* package. After resampling, I would impute missing values by chained equations using the *mice* package. Finally, I would estimate the adjusted hazard ratio for amputation using an interval-censored version of the Cox PH model, specifically the one in the *icenReg* package (ic_sp).

The idea is to bootstrap all these steps about 2000 times to account for all the uncertainties arising from clustering, imputation and interval-censoring in one framework. Not sure how to deal with competing risk, though. #edit: combined endpoint amputation+Death would be possible!

I would like to hear opinions about that plan and would be open to experiences with these specific packages or suggestions for a other solution to these challenges. Maybe someone is aware of simulation studies for these issues, like that one: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1602.07933v1.pdf

Comment: I've always balked at time to event analyses calling death a "censoring event" - For any health related outcome, it's certain to be informative censoring, and a composite endpoint should be preferred.

Comment: Thanks! A composite endpoint would certainly be an option.